# is there 100ms of window after user clicks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I've read an article to introduce the [FLIP](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/), and one crucial point is that

> There is a window of 100ms after someone interacts with your site where you’re able to do work without them noticing.

since this article is written in 2015, so I wonder if there's a official docs about it, has it changed over time?

Comment: The principle is about human perception, not about technical limitations. It's possible, but highly unlikely, that human perception changed in the few years.

Comment: I though it was a browser behavior 

Comment: I know that when my wife sends me a grocery list that it takes me over an hour to notice.  Does that help?

Comment: Note that there is also a technical limitation, the rendering will be done at the next VSync, and will hit the monitor the next frame. Add to that the delay that USB/BT polling rate + the time that the browser picks the OS message, we users actually got used of such delays, that's why it's acceptable. However, you're right that during the last few years a lot of work has been made to make everything more responsive, from what was considered Gamers mice specs in 2015 available in now low level products to high-FPS monitors etc. That window may get thinner and thinner in the near future.